# Docker Desktop is giving me "Builder error" for the builder desktop-Windows

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I am completely new to Docker.  The only thing I have done is install Docker Desktop.  When I go to Builders I see that desktop-windows has an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7jSD.png).

I have no idea to where to start about resolving this issue.

Things I've tried:

- I have tried uninstalling and re-stalling Docker Desktop.
- I rebooted my computer.
- I "Restart" from the Docker Desktop UI.
- I "Rest to factory defaults" from the Docker Desktop UI.

I am using Windows 11.  Docker Desktop version 4.26.1, which is the latest version at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Windows 11 Home edition your OS doesnt support Hyper-V so Windows Containers on Windows wont work which i think is what that error is about. Linux containers on Windows are based on Windows SubSystem for Linux (WSL) which is available on Home edition. If this is the case this isnt really an error and more of a known limitation. You should be able to build and run Linux containers regardless of this error. If you want to run Windows containers you will need to upgrade Windows to Professional edition and then re-install docker.

NOTE: Do NOT click `Switch to Windows Containers` in the Docker tray icon if your on a Windows Home edition. I did this and had to edit a docker config file to get back to Linux Containers mode.

You can test what edition of Windows is installed from an Elevated PowerShell prompt as follows:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsEdition -Online


Edition : Professional
```